# How can I change etherbase in pyethapp?

Tags: pyethapp

I want to change `etherbase` in pyethapp, but couldn't find something like `setEtherbase` in geth.
How can I change `etherbase` (`coinbase` or `eth.coinbase`) in pyethapp?

Answer (score 2):

From the [code](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/blob/5e410243a8eac263c50060e0af67baf1a857ea32/pyethapp/accounts.py#L244):

> The coinbase address is given by the config field pow.coinbase_hex. If
>   this does not exist or is `None`, the address of the first account is
>   used instead. If there are no accounts, the coinbase is
>   `DEFAULT_COINBASE`.

For reference, `DEFAULT_COINBASE` is defined in that file as:

```
DEFAULT_COINBASE = 'de0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae'.decode('hex')
```

You have a several options:

- If you have no accounts created in this instantiation of Pyethapp - nor intend to create any in future - you could redefine `DEFAULT_COINBASE` in your copy of the code. Probably not the best idea, because you're bound to want to explicitly create accounts at some point...
- If you haven't set that config variable, then you're just using the first account you created as your coinbase. Removing that account will shuffle everything up one, meaning the second account becomes the new coinbase, etc...
- If you want to explicitly configure the coinbase using the `coinbase_hex` flag, you'll need to follow the configuration instructions on the Pyethapp wiki pages: https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/Configuring-and-Logging#command-line-options

As always, make sure your keystore is backed up before playing around with anything.